# My JavaScript code is not being run linearly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, global-variables

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I have been attempting to create a Chrome extension. The Chrome extension basically searches for a certain "set" of bookmarks and adds them into an array. I think this will be easier to explain with the code:

```
var books = [];

function getBookmarks(){
    console.log("Bookmarks!");

    chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bookmarks){
        search_for_title(bookmarks, "Music", null, books); //Collect all bookmarks in the "Music" folder and put them into the books array
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i++){ //Once all bookmarks are added to the books array, loop through all of them
        console.log("ITEM: " + books[i]);
    }
    console.log("books: " + books.length); //Print out the length of the books array
}

function search_for_title(bookmarks, title, parent){

    if(parent == null){ //First find the parent folder

        for(var i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++){ //Loop through all bookmarks

            if(bookmarks[i].title == title){ //If the bookmark title matches the title of the folder we're looking for ("Music"), proceed                    
                search_for_title(bookmarks[i].children, null, bookmarks[i].id); //Loop through all the bookmarks in the folder that we found

                console.log("books length: " + books.length);
            } else{
                if(bookmarks[i].children){ //If the bookmark is a folder, it has children                        
                    search_for_title(bookmarks[i].children, title, parent);
                }
            }
        }
    } else if(title == null){ //Parent folder is found, now just traverse the bookmarks within
        for(var i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++){
            console.log("books[" + i + "] = " + bookmarks[i].title + " , books length: " + books.length);
            books[i] = bookmarks[i].title; //Assign all the bookmarks into the books array
        }
    }
}

getBookmarks();

console.log("FINAL BOOKS: " + books.length);
```

A few things to notice: var books = [] is declared and initialized at a global scope, the function search_for_title recurses, and getBookmarks() is called at the end of this code snippet to initiate the code.

Now, I'm usually from a Java and C++ background where everything acts linearly and there are none of these "callback" functions that I'm new to. So, I think the output should be:

1. Bookmarks!
2. **-Print out all of the bookmarks in the "Music" folder and return back to the getBookmarks function-**
3. ITEM:...
4. ITEM:...
5. ITEM:...
6. ...
7. Books: 625 ** (the length that books should be)**
8. FINAL BOOKS: 625

However, the output I have been getting is:

1. Bookmarks! **This is good**
2. books: 0 **Why  is this at the Beginning?** *This value should be 625*
3. FINAL BOOKS: 0 **Why especially is the last line of code in the program at nearly the Beginning?** *This value should be 625*
4. -All of the bookmarks that were found- **This is good**
5. Books length: 0 **This should be near the beginning of the program, like the 2nd line** *Correct value of 0*

I am CLEARLY directly accessing the global "books" array in the search_for_title method, but for some reason it always tells me that the array is length 0. Also, my code for some reason seems like it has no linear path whatsoever and it's just jumping all over the place. Also, when the program prints out each individual bookmark, it prints out the correct length of the books array (i.e. books[599] = Nero - Promises - YouTube, books length: 600), but why does it always say length 0 when it returns back to the getBookmarks function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is running linearly, however the `chrome.bookmarks.getTree` method is an asynchronous call. That means the code after the #getTree method doesn't wait until the method is complete.

In JavaScript functions are first class objects. The callback function is being passed into the #getTree method which executes the argument function after performing its own logic.

In your current code, your log results will vary slightly each time as each asynchronous call will take a different amount of time to complete. You should be able to make this work by simply moving your loop and log code inside the callback function.

```
function getBookmarks(){
  console.log("Bookmarks!");

  chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bookmarks){
    search_for_title(bookmarks, "Music", null, books); //Collect all bookmarks in the "Music" folder and put them into the books array

    for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i++){ //Once all bookmarks are added to the books array, loop through all of them
      console.log("ITEM: " + books[i]);
    }
    console.log("books: " + books.length); //Print out the length of the books array
  });
}
```

Comment: The Chrome API currently uses callback functions when dealing with functions that make asynchronous calls, however when writing your own AJAX calls look into promises. Callback functions can be confusing and hard to maintain when you start nesting them, promises fix that.

Comment: Thanks so much!  So will I have to write all of my remaining code within that chrome.bookmarks.getTree method now?  How will I know it's finished so I can just write normal code in the getBookmarks() function?  Are callbacks made for the exact reason that fixed my problem?